# Submit Button not getting correct route to add new data in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I am facing problem for Submit Button not getting correct route to add new data.
2 Blade file with 2 Submit Button which need to save 2 data to 2 different tables.

Problem facing - Data submitted in 1 table for both submit button....

addnewBuffalo.blade.php

```
  <div class="box-header with-border" align="right">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn"><i class="fa fa-floppy-o"></i> <b>Add 
    Buffalo</b></button><a href="" class="btn btn-warning btn"><i class="fa fa-refresh"> 
    </i> <b> Refresh</b></a>
  </div>
```

addnewcow.blade.php

```
  <div class="box-header with-border" align="right">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn"><i class="fa fa-floppy-o"></i> <b>Add 
    Cow</b></button><a href="" class="btn btn-warning btn"><i class="fa fa-refresh"></i> <b> 
    Refresh</b></a> 
  </div>
```

web.php

```
  Route:: post('submit', 'App\Http\Controllers\addnewbuffaloController@addbuffaloData') 
          ->name('submit');

  Route:: post('submit', 'App\Http\Controllers\addnewcowController@addcowData') 
          ->name('submit');
```

Comment: Your cant use same URI with same method at a time

Answer (score 0):

You need to create 2 separate Route Names. Having ->name('submit') for both won't work. And having the same path won't work

```
Route::post('submit=buffalo', 'App\Http\Controllers\addnewbuffaloController@addbuffaloData') 
          ->name('submit-buffalo');
Route::post('submit-cow', 'App\Http\Controllers\addnewcowController@addcowData') 
          ->name('submit-cow');
```

Or if the form is wrapped by one form tag then you can handle both submissions in the one Controller action

```
<button type="submit" name="buffalo-submission">Save Buffalo</button>
<button type="submit" name="cow-submission">Save Cow</button>
```

Then in the controller action code you could check

```
if ($request->has('buffalo-submission') { 
    Do buffalo code 
} else if ($request->has('cow-submission')) { 
    do cow code 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for Reply.... I am new self learner.... So asking this question.... Where did i need to route name ....... i Guess i should be in  form tag....                                                                 
<form method="POST" action="submit" accept-charset="UTF-8" enctype="multipart/form-data"><input name="_token" type="hidden" value="">

Comment: If you have a form wrapping the entire table then you can't make it submit to 2 different areas without using javascript. 

What you could do is have 1 form submission, and you can handle the 2 different types of forms based on the submit button name. name="buffalo-submission" name="cow-submission" on each button. Then in the code you could check if ($request->has('buffalo-submission') { Do buffalo code } else if ($request->has('cow-submission')) { do cow code }